# Validate user entered Phone number with certain length using Redux Form and Input Mask

Tags: redux-form, input-mask

Even the user has entered only 1 number, the validation is not working, I think the problem that occurs with maskChar value of Inputmask.

````
               <Field
                component={NumberField}
                name="phone"
                mask="+1 (999) 999-9999"
                placeholder="Phone"
              />```

```
         <InputMask
          mask={mask}
          maskChar={maskChar}
          {...input}
          value={toUpper && input.value.trim()}
          label={label}
          onFocus={() => isActive(true)}
          onBlur={() => isActive(false)}
          placeholder={active ? '' : thePlaceholder}
          aria-label={label}
          type={type}
          required={required}
        />
`
``
````

Answer (score 0):

If you have no problem with new NPM package this one looks good: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

or this one:

https://catamphetamine.github.io/react-phone-number-input/

https://github.com/catamphetamine/react-phone-number-input

or you can check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51337455/1037613)